# DirectShow RenderFile from Network URL has serious flaw. How to avoid it?

Tags: windows, winapi, audio, audio-streaming, directshow

I use DirectShow IGraphBuilder::RenderFile function to play audio stream from network URL. It is the real-time audio stream.

It works how it should, the problem is when internet connection is stopped for too long time, if it stops for a short time, it's no problem, it will continue playing after internet connection is restored, however when internet connection is stopped for too long time, like few minutes or more. After it is restored, playing is not continued, and state of graph is like it is being played.

How to avoid this situation? Or how I can detect that audio has stopped? IMediaControl::GetState returns state like it is being played.

Comment: You can set a timer on the downstream filter which periodically checks whether the upstream filter is still active. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865315/how-can-a-filter-implementing-istream-know-when-it-wont-receive-any-further-ist).

Answer (score 0):

To understand what part of the pipeline lets you down you need to get a better understanding of your filter graph topology. Specifically, I would guess that your source filter is a third party component, and it is the source of the mentioned problem, but you are yet unaware what it is exactly. Claiming that `IGraphBuilder::RenderFile` is doing something wrong in regard to handling network disconnection is unlikely to get you closer to a solution.

Next troubleshooting step you should take is identification of participating filters and finding out details of their streaming and error handling. [Understanding Your DirectShow Filter Graph](http://alax.info/blog/1678) continues on explaining how to get the topology of your graph and why it is so important.

Comment: Nice answer but not helpful. There are no third party components. Just original pure and clean windows 10, visual studio 2019, and simple code(creating graph, calling IGraphBuilder::RenderFile on any radio stream URL). You can test it by yourself and you will see that flaw is in directshow itself. Render network file, disconnect internet connection for few minutes, and connect again.

Comment: So how do you know you don't have third party components? My post explains that in order to understand your graph you need to be able to inspect it. `RenderFile` is in particular a method one would normally avoid just because of creating confusion between what you expect and what actually runs. When you manage to inspect your graph, you could also share the topology by attaching an image (like the one with pink background in my post) to this question.

Comment: Also if you have a radio URL then why don't you include it in the question? There are multiple options to deliver audio on internet not to mention codecs, repsective playback topologies vary as well.